# ¿Que son debounce y throttle en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

He visto que son metodos que usualmente hacen los que escriben JavaScript para ayuda o para un fin en concreto pero no estoy muy seguro de que hace cada uno.

Comment: Hola José. Has probado a leer la documentacion?

Answer (score 10):

[`Throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) fija un máximo de ejecuciones por intervalo de tiempo. Por ejemplo, permite la ejecución de esta función un máximo de una vez cada 500 ms.

> **throttle(fn, wait, [options])** (traducción)
>
> Toma una función como parámetro y devuelve una nueva versión de la
>   función que, cuando es invocada de manera repetida, no se ejecutará más
>   de una vez por cada espera en milisegundos.

[`Debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) fija un tiempo mínimo entre ejecuciones. Por ejemplo, ejecuta esta función con un mínimo de 500 ms entre ejecuciones consecutivas.

> **debounce(fn, wait, [immediate])** (traducción)
>
> Toma una función como parámetro y devuelve una nueva versión de la
>   función que, cuando es invocada, no se ejecutará hasta que no haya
>   transcurrido un tiempo de espera en milisegundos.
>
> Esto significa que si es llamada en una sucesión rápida la función
>   se ejecutará únicamente una vez, cuando haya finalizado la avalancha
>   de llamadas.

---

Notas:

- `throttle` dispone de cambios en su funcionalidad gracias a las opciones. Por defecto se realiza la llamada la primera vez que se llama a la función y una vez adicional tras el tiempo de espera, como haría `debounce`. Configurando a `false` el valor de `leading` y/o `trailing` podemos hacer que no se llame a la función inmediatamente la primera vez o que tras la última vez pasado el tiempo de espera.
- `debounce`, por su parte, dispone de un único cambio en su funcionalidad a través de la opción inmediata, que realiza la llamada inmediatamente (en vez de posponerla). Puede servir, por ejemplo, para evitar el envío de un formulario por culpa de un doble clic en un botón de envío.